# MIME type for HTML5 in strict XML syntax (XHTML5??, for Mobile Safari)?

Tags: xml, html, mime-types

I have to generate a HTML page for Mobile Safari only. So I have chosen HTML in strict XML syntax. But I don't know how should I set MIME type for this kind of document.

Comment: This has to done at the HTTP level, either by server configuration or the server-side scripting language. What are you using?

Answer (score 3):

You should set the mime as `text/html`, **not** `application/xml`.

The latter will put your browser in an unforgiving parsing mode, where any malformed syntax will cause the page to completely error.

Why does this matter? You may have a CMS or something external that accidentally places some invalid XML on your page; would you rather your site not be visible to anyone or would you rather the browser gracefully recover? I know what I would prefer.

Also, I believe HTML5 should always have the `text/html` mime type; the syntax you use is optional (self closing tags can have `/>` or just `>`).

Comment: What if the OP wants unforgiving parsing mode? I often do. Catches errors early. `application/xml` and `application/xhtml+xml` are both valid ways of serving XHTML5.

Comment: @Alohci if having your page unusable is an option for you, great. But I often have CMSs which don't always produce the best output.

Comment: I'm sorry guys, but I need the unforgiving parsing mode :) Because of exactly @Alohci said. And my page won't be unusable because my target browser is fixed.

Comment: @Eornil Set it as `application/xml` then. Just because your target browser is fixed doesn't mean an XML error isn't a serious issue.

Comment: It is estimated that 99% of webpages are erroneous (mininum 1 error per page). Let us follow the standards and make the web cleaner. I would opt for unforgiving parse mode.